# Combination Generator in JAVA

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to find all combinations of items in several arrays. The number of arrays is random (this can be 2, 3, 4, 5...). The number of elements in each array is random too.

e.g., I have the 3 arrays :

```
String[][] array1 = {{"A1","A2","A3"},{"B1","B2","B3"},{"C1","C2"}};
```

I would like to generate an array with all possible combinations :

> ```
> A1, B1, C1
> A1, B1, C2
> A1, B2, C1
> A1, B2, C2
> A1, B3, C1
> A1, B3, C2
> A2, B1, C1
> A2, B1, C2 ...
> ```

Comment: Use a 2D array to pass a variable number of arrays : String[][]

Comment: @Eran Ok but that is not the solution i am looking for what i need is to generate combinations.

Comment: Hope this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30196382/3459206 There is a Java code to generate all possible combinations by given source arrays of different length (`next()` and `generateWord()` methods can be easily adopted to your case).

Comment: You want to compute the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the input arrays. This may (or may not) help to find existing implementations. (Just one [example](https://github.com/javagl/Combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/utils/math/combinatorics/MixedRangeCombinationIterable.java))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the combinations by using a "counter-like" strategy, i.e. treat those arrays as digits of a number like this:

```
public static String[][] generateCombinations(String[]... arrays) {
    if (arrays.length == 0) {
        return new String[][]{{}};
    }
    int num = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        num *= arrays[i].length;
    }

    String[][] result = new String[num][arrays.length];

    // array containing the indices of the Strings
    int[] combination = new int[arrays.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        String[] comb = result[i];
        // fill array
        for (int j = 0; j < arrays.length; j++) {
            comb[j] = arrays[j][combination[j]];
        }

        // generate next combination
        for (int j = arrays.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            int n = ++combination[j];
            if (n >= arrays[j].length) {
                // "digit" exceeded valid range -> back to 0 and continue incrementing
                combination[j] = 0;
            } else {
                // "digit" still in valid range -> stop
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The method is called like this:

```
generateCombinations(
            new String[]{"A1","A2","A3"},
            new String[]{"B1","B2","B3"},
            new String[]{"C1","C2"}
       )
```

or like this:

```
generateCombinations(array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches to variable loop nesting. One is explicit bookkeeping, as discussed in the prior [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30503497/1798593). The other is a recursive solution. In a recursive solution activations of the recursive method store as local variables the same index data as is tracked in an explicit array in the bookkeeping approach.

The base case for the recursion is to return a length 0 result array if the input contains zero arrays. If the input contains one or more arrays, generate the result from the elements of the first array and the recursive call result for the remaining arrays.